# expand.grid with separate variable for each column

Tags: r, combinations

I would like to achieve the following `data.frame` in R:

```
    i1   i2   i3
1   A1   A2   A3
2   No   A2   A3
3   A1   No   A3
4   No   No   A3
5   A1   A2   No
6   No   A2   No
7   A1   No   No
8   No   No   No
```

In each column the variable can either be the concatenated string *"A"* and the column number or *"No"*. The `data.frame` should contain all possible combinations.

My idea was to use `expand.grid`, but I don't know how to create the `list` dynamically. Or is there a better approach?

```
expand.grid(list(c("A1", "No"), c("A2", "No"), c("A3", "No")))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you could create your own helper function, something like that

```
MyList <- function(n) expand.grid(lapply(paste0("A", seq_len(n)), c, "No"))
```

Then simply pass it the number of elements (e.g., 3)

```
MyList(3)
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1   A1   A2   A3
# 2   No   A2   A3
# 3   A1   No   A3
# 4   No   No   A3
# 5   A1   A2   No
# 6   No   A2   No
# 7   A1   No   No
# 8   No   No   No
```

---

Alternatively, you could also try `data.table`s `CJ` equivalent which should much more efficient than `expand.grid` for a big `n`

```
library(data.table)
DTCJ <- function(n) do.call(CJ, lapply(paste0("A", seq_len(n)), c, "No"))
DTCJ(3) # will return a sorted cross join
#    V1 V2 V3
# 1: A1 A2 A3
# 2: A1 A2 No
# 3: A1 No A3
# 4: A1 No No
# 5: No A2 A3
# 6: No A2 No
# 7: No No A3
# 8: No No No
```

Comment: @Ananda, unfortunately `CJ` doesn't work with a list object and I was going to ask Arun about it. Maybe akruns `data.frame` will work, don't know

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using `Map` with `expand.grid`

```
 n <- 3
 expand.grid(Map(c, paste0('A', seq_len(n)), 'NO'))
```

Or

```
 expand.grid(as.data.frame(rbind(paste0('A', seq_len(n)),'NO')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, only using the most fundamental functions in R, is to use the indices:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c('A','A','A', 'A',rep('No',4)), V2 = c('A','A','No','No','A','A','No','No'), V3 = c('A','No','A','No','A','No','A','No'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

to get the row and col indices of the elements we need to change:

```
rindex <- which(df != 'No') %% nrow(df)
cindex <- ceiling(which(df != 'No')/nrow(df))
```

the solution is basically a one-liner:

```
df[matrix(c(rindex,cindex),ncol=2)] <- paste0(df[matrix(c(rindex,cindex),ncol=2)],cindex)

> df

  V1 V2 V3
1 A1 A2 A3
2 A1 A2 No
3 A1 No A3
4 A1 No No
5 No A2 A3
6 No A2 No
7 No No A3
8 No No No
```

Comment: What `df` are you referring to? The OP didn't provide a data set. I would guess they actually trying to avoid of creating one.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, see my edit. I built the df that the OP used when asking for a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see this `df` anywhere. All OP provided was his desired output.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, you are right but you can infer a possible df from his question:
> In each column the variable can either be the concatenated string "A" and the column number or "No". The data.frame should contain all possible combinations.